# Delete date in log by using sed

Tags: bash, shell, logging, sed, tr

How can I delete all lines that not equal by date in the log by using the sed command?

I collect all logs, and would like to have just last 24 hours by:
`find <path to log> -type f -newermt $(date -d -24hour +%Y-%m-%d) -name <FILE_NAME>`
Time at log by:`$(date +%F)`

After collecting all this to a file I would like clean all logs that not equal to the last 24 hours how can I write that does not fit by: 'sed' or 'tr --delete' for example.

Comment: I recommend `grep` to get all lines matching a certain pattern.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include a sample of your input and the corresponding desired output.

Comment: What will be the command for grep?
I can use 'grep -Ev' but would like to delete from exist file

Comment: @G.Guy how does the log file look like, kindly consider sharing a sample

Comment: Please avoid *"Give me the codez"* questions. Instead show the script you are working on and state where the problem is. Also see [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/261592/608639)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We gladly help, but sadly I have to say that this question is asked in so many flavours that you could easily find some answers. Eg. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51045629 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51994718 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50014023 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30728548 and ...

Comment: @Alfe If you are going to use `sed` afterwards, you can just use `sed` itself to get lines matching a certain pattern.

Comment: @ingroxd Of course.  So?  I still recommend using `grep` ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Found this solution: `sed "/^$(date -d -24hour '+%F')/!d" temp`

Comment: This solution will only work if `$(date -d -24hour '+%F')` is part of the file. If it is not, it will not work. Imagine that your system was down for one hour just at that time. No logs are generated and thus your script fails.

Comment: You are right, but the files here are a log, so will be the date (and can be a line not started with a date, a bug, there will not stay, unfortunately)